# Lightweight code editor with smart reflow of comments

Tags: windows, text-editor, editor

Is there exist a lightweight code editor with the ability of smart reflow of comments, as shown here?

```
        50-characters column
|<---------------------------------------------->|

// Initial code
if (a == b) {
    // Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
}

// Then we move the caret on the comment, press
// Ctrl-Q and this long line will be splitted into 3
// shorter ones:
if (a == b) {
    // Test test test test test test test test
    // test test test test test test test test
    // test test test test test
}

// Then we may think that the 2nd line contains
// some non-relevant information and trim it slightly:
if (a == b) {
    // Test test test test test test test test
    // test test
    // test test test test test
}

// And then, after the 2nd line is trimmed, we press
// Alt-Q again and now we have 2 lines instead of 3:
if (a == b) {
    // Test test test test test test test test
    // test test test test test test test
}
```

I know, Vim and Emacs probably can do it, but they are too hard to use for me. Also, Visual Studio Code and Sublime Text can do it - sometimes I use them in my work, but currently I need editor which will start faster (instantly) and with less RAM consumption.

Comment: Nowadays, Visual Studio Code is often considered fairly light and fast-starting already! Sublime Text is even lighter and faster. Honestly, I'm not sure you can really do much better than Sublime Text. Why do you need something so light and so fast? Are you on an ancient machine or something?

Comment: @JohnY My computer is fairly ancient (2010). I need an editor for quick fixes - double-click on some file, make a quick fix in lightweight editor and then close it. Everything should be instantly. Sublime oftenly starts about 3-4 seconds (without plugins) - too long for this case. VSC is cool, but I use it for full-day work, instead of quick fixes.

Comment: Also, for futher readers: to use this option in Visual Studio Code you need [ReWrap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stkb.rewrap) extension. It's not possible without it.

Comment: Since I doubt there is any existing editor that meets your requirements, my suggestion would be to adjust your workflow. For example, always keep a full-featured editor open, and do your quick fixes there. Or write your own rewrapper (not necessarily a plugin for some other editor, but rather with something like AutoHotkey, which would handle copying to the clipboard, rewrapping, and pasting back; so it would *look* more-or-less like the editor is doing it even though the editor is not involved at all).

Comment: " Visual Studio can do it" - how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/cudatext/) editor can do it with plugin **CudaExt**.

- set in user.json option "margin" to some value, e.g. 80
- install CudaExt via Plugins/AddonManager
- call F1 dialog, find command "Re-wrap comment at caret"
- in this dialog, press F9 to set hotkey, e.g. Ctrl+Q

Now you can press hotkey on multiline comment to re-flow it.

[image: CudaExt cmd]

Comment: Updated answer, need to set CudaText option "margin" in user.json.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look into [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which seems to be nearly as capable as Emacs, but faster and lighter.

Comment: Yes, I already tried as described here: https://superuser.com/questions/100010/how-can-a-paragraph-be-reformatted-in-notepad. It doesn't properly work. Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/qylRrSh

Comment: What about a three-step sequence: (1) uncomment, (2) wrap, (3) recomment the wrapped block

Comment: Hm. In Notepad++ it doesn't actually improve anything, because the second line isn't indented: https://jsfiddle.net/ozrxdfkg/ . However, It's interesting idea itself (thanks), and it could work, probably, in some another editor.

Comment: Did you also spot [this question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/484578/how-can-i-indent-the-wrapped-text-in-notepad)?

Comment: Yes, after you posted this link :) It doesn't resolve the issue, however. It changes how soft-wrapping looks. Instead, in my example we have to deal with hard-wrapping.

Comment: If you're reasonably fluent in Python, it's entirely possible that you can use the [NPP Python Script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) to write the functionality you're looking for...

Comment: Suggesting Notepad++ without proper plugin for topic, is not good.